# How to create an event handler for objects in array?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I'm making a game in which an ellipse is created whenever random number generated is 6. But all of these objects are in an array. Whenever last object of ellipse is created then event handler only works for it and not for previous objects . I've used sender argument to recognize the source but it gives and exception . Here's my code

```
public static Ellipse[] greenEllipse = new Ellipse[10];


Game.green++;
 Game.greenEllipse[green] = new Ellipse();
                    SolidColorBrush s = new SolidColorBrush();
                    s.Color = Colors.Green;
                    SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                    blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;

                    // Set Ellipse's width and color
                    greenEllipse[green].StrokeThickness = 2;
                    greenEllipse[green].Stroke = blackBrush;
                    // Fill rectangle with blue color
                    greenEllipse[green].Fill = s;
                    greenEllipse[green].Height = 40;
                    greenEllipse[green].Width = 45;
                    greenEllipse[green].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = -200, Y = -72 };
                    greenEllipse[green].PointerPressed += OnClickge;
                    g.Children.Add(greenEllipse[green]);



private void OnClickge(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var ocg = sender;
            tt.Text = nee.ToString();
            if (green1 < 4 && nee != 5 && nee != 6)
            {
                Game.px += nee * 40;
                Game.greenEllipse[Convert.ToInt32(ocg)].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = px, Y = py };

                green1 += nee;

            }

            if (nee == 5)
            {

                Game.py += (nee) * (-20);
                Game.greenEllipse[Convert.ToInt32(ocg)].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = px + nee, Y = py };
            }
            if (green1 > 4)
            {
                if (nee != 5)
                {
                    green1--;
                    Game.py += nee * (-20);
                    Game.greenEllipse[Convert.ToInt32(ocg)].RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = px + nee, Y = py };
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: Sender should be the Ellipse that raised the event. I would not expect you could convert it to an Int32

Comment: If its an ellipse then how can i apply render transform property to it.?

Comment: var ocg = sender as Ellipse;  Then you can apply the render transform to ocg.